# gVIM on Windows 7 crashes due to COMCTL32.dll

Tags: windows-7, gvim, dll

My gVIM 7.4 (and also 7.3 before that) keeps crashing when I work on .py files (other files don't cause the problem). The crashes appear periodically but unpredictably - at least to me there doesn't seem to be a clearly identifiable cause.

The error report gives me this (pardon the German):

```
Problemsignatur:
  Problemereignisname:  APPCRASH
  Anwendungsname:   gvim.exe
  Anwendungsversion:    7.4.280.0
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    5206345a
  Fehlermodulname:  COMCTL32.dll
  Fehlermodulversion:   6.10.7601.18837
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   553a8345
  Ausnahmecode: c0000005
  Ausnahmeoffset:   000abd26
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
  Gebietsschema-ID: 1031
  Zusatzinformation 1:  0a9e
  Zusatzinformation 2:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
  Zusatzinformation 3:  0a9e
  Zusatzinformation 4:  0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

Using the Event Manager I could identify the culprit:

```
C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.18837_none_41e855142bd5705d\COMCTL32.dll
```

There seem to be quite a number of COMCTL32.dlls on my machine, actually. 
I checked the system using `sfc /scannow` and `DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /Scanhealth` but no problems were identified. Other GUI applications don't show any type of problem.

Judging by the fact that it's only py-files, it must be one of my Python Plugins that is causing this but they are all stable versions and didn't use to cause trouble. So it must be my system (Windows 7 Professional with all current updates, 64 bit).

Any idea on how to find the causing problem or fix the dll file?

Comment: [There is a logical system](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682586(v=vs.85).aspx), to how Windows will find and locate a required dll, a program uses.  A program can bypass this order by specifically indicating it wants a specific static file. So determine what the current date, size, and version of the dll should be, locate a file that matches that information and place it in the program's directory.  It is extremely odd the program would be using a file located in the WinSxS directory.  That isn't a directory normally used.

Comment: "it must be one of my Python Plugins" - You should eliminate this possibility.  Disable the plugins, if the crash happens, then you know it isn't your plugins.  I would wager a bet, since the application is using the source file from the directory WinSxS ( i know its not corrupt because those commands you ran didn't indicate a problem ) I bet the problem is caused by a plug-in

Comment: @Ramhound: I am sure it is one of the python plugins, because no problems appear when I edit other files. The plugins in vim are loaded depending on filetype.
Thanks for the tip with the dll. I tried placing one in the right dir, lets see what will happen. However the page you linked said that already loaded dll's will be loaded in first place, so I'd assume this won't help.

Comment: The link indicates the order Windows will use to locate a DLL.  I point that out because you indicated your system has lots of copies, well unless the single copy that was used was corrupt, then the dll isn't at fault.  Hence the reason I told you to find a good copy, and place it in the very first location ( the directory with the application itself) to eliminate that possibility.

Comment: "If a DLL with the same module name is already loaded in memory, the system checks only for redirection and a manifest before resolving to the loaded DLL, no matter which directory it is in. The system does not search for the DLL." - I interpret this in the way that no searching is performed, if COMCTL32.dll is already loaded in memory. In this case a copy in the app directory wouldn't help, right?)

Comment: Sure;  I presumed that its very likely gVIM is the only application running that is loading that file though.  If not there are other things you can do, to verify that is the case, and things you can do to unload all instance of the file.  Still waiting on you to verify the problem is caused by plugins or not.

Comment: If I don't load the python plugins, gVIM does indeed not cause the dll to crash. The thing is that the plugins are all well-developed and stable - didn't use to cause any trouble. Which is why I'd like to think it is a dll problem. Been running on a copied dll for an hour now, by the way! :)

Comment: So now your job is determine which plugin it is.  We can go from there once you know that.

Comment: Didn't yet determine the culprit plugin. However the error reports show  that the DLL that is loaded still resides in `C:\Windows\WinSxS\` . So copying the dll in the application directory didn't help.